# Link as a button-like appearance

Tags: css, navigation, hover

How do I change the background color of a link (which appears as a button) when mouse over the link in a horizontal navigator bar?

Code of HTML

```
  <head>

         <style>

                #menu li 
                {
                     display:inline;
                     border-style:solid;
                     boreder-top : none;
                     border-bottom : none;
                     margin-right : -8px;
                     padding-top : 0px;
                     padding-bottom : 0px;
                     padding-left : 25px;
                     padding-right : 25px;
                 }

                 #menu li a:hover{background-color:#00FFFF;}
         </style>

  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="menu">
              <ul class="nav">
                   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="college.php">College</a></li>
                   <li><a href="education.php">Education</a></li>
                   <li><a href="research.php">Research</a></li>
                   <li><a href="faculty.php">Faculty & Staff</a></li>
                   <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>
   </body>
```

When I keep the mouse over the links in the navigation bar, it only changes the color of the background of the content area. It ignores the padding area.

I want to change the color of the background of the content + padding.

Comment: Please provide your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: It's because the `:hover` is on the `a` instead of the `li`.

Comment: I have edited my question with the whole code. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the padding declarations to the `a` element, display them as block elements and display the `li`s as `inline-block`.

```
#menu li {
    display : inline-block;
    border-style : solid;
    boreder-top : none;
    border-bottom : none;
    margin-right : -8px;
    padding-top : 0px;
    padding-bottom : 0px;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding-left : 25px;
    padding-right : 25px;
}

#menu li a:hover{ 
    background-color:#00FFFF;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sK2d9/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your css hover link is a bit off.

If you have given your buttons a id of menu then a css format should look like so:

```
.menu:hover {
background-color:#00FFFF;
}
```

Try that, that's all I can think of may be wrong but yeah.

Comment: yeah css hover is a bit off. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put hover on `<li></li>`.
by default CSS will change the padding area color too.
like this: [[ LINK ]](http://jsfiddle.net/2GBqE/)

Comment: Thank u sooooooo much. Working perfectly